# Regular Expressions: How would I extract a given word using a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

How would I extract the word 'wrestle' from the following:

```
type=weaksubj len=1 word1=wrestle pos1=verb stemmed1=y priorpolarity=negative
```

using a regular expression?

Comment: Depends. Are you looking for the first word after 'word1='? Could it have upper and lower case characters? Other special characters? I find that once you think about these things the regex almost writes itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The question is not very clear, but I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
word1=(\w+)
```

Your match will be in the 1st group. Here's some sample Python code:

```
import re
yourstring = 'type=weaksubj len=1 word1=wrestle pos1=verb stemmed1=y priorpolarity=negative'

m = re.search(r'word1=(\w+)', yourstring)
print m.group(1)
```

As seen on [codepad](http://codepad.org/ozXUtLbX). A more generalized solution:

```
import re
def get_attr(str, attr):
    m = re.search(attr + r'=(\w+)', str)
    return None if not m else m.group(1)

str = 'type=weaksubj len=1 word1=wrestle pos1=verb stemmed1=y priorpolarity=negative'

print get_attr(str, 'word1')  # wrestle
print get_attr(str, 'type')   # weaksubj
print get_attr(str, 'foo')    # None
```

Also available on [codepad](http://codepad.org/zWExcuvj)

Answer (score 2):

Given the following regex...

```
/word1=(\w+)/
```

...$1 or whatever your first match is in your language will be wrestle.

Comment: I believe it's `result = re.match(pattern, string)`

Comment: @Ruel: You want `re.search()`, not `re.match()`. The latter always anchors the search to the start of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You regex would be something like this

```
/.*word1=(\w+)/
```

Comment: If you edit your answer, it would be nice to comment about it. I was confused for a while why this wouldn't work. Though the starting `.*` is still pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Use: `/word1=(\w+)/`

Comment: Yep, thanks about that. Edited. The non-greedy matching caused the regex to match a single character only. :P

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is always separated by spaces

```
word1=([^ ]+)
```

Then you can get the value by the first group match.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe re is unnecessary when str.split looks like it will suffice:

```
>>> s = "type=weaksubj len=1 word1=wrestle pos1=verb stemmed1=y priorpolarity=negative"
>>> dd = dict(ss.split('=',1) for ss in s.split())
>>> dd['word1']
'wrestle'
```